# MathNet - 'System.TypeInitializationException'

Tags: c#, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I am trying to parse string of expression using MathNet in C# and when I try this code:

`var h = MathNet.Symbolics.Infix.ParseOrUndefined("1/(a*b)");`

it threw exception.

*"An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in MathNet.Symbolics.dll*

Additional information: The type initializer for '.$Infix' threw an exception."

Where am I wrong?
I used *MathNet v.0.6.0.0* and *Visual Studio 2012 Express*

## Updated

It was solved by hotfix by windows which is my bad not to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the dependencies. Can you list what exact package versions of them you're using? And what .Net version you're compiling against.

Assuming you have installed Math.NET Symbolics via NuGet, can you try to update all dependencies (with NuGet)?

Edit: I cannot reproduce this with newer VisualStudio versions - is there a chance you could upgrade, e.g. to [VisualStudio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) which is free as well?

Comment: all of the dependencies are updated.
this is the  log i got

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$MathNet-Symbolics>.$Infix' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
   at FParsec.InfixOperator`3..ctor(String operatorString, FSharpFunc`2 afterStringParser, Int32 precedence, Associativity associativity, FSharpFunc`2 mapping)
   at <StartupCode$MathNet-Symbolics>.$Infix..cctor()

Comment: Ok, now, that's another beast. There have been issues causing this, but to my understanding have been fixed by hotfixes - is your system up to date with all windows updates?

Comment: aw! I see. Thank you. :)
i forgot to search for solution of internal exception not the external. My bad.

Comment: Can you try again with v0.7.1 (and FParsec 1.0.1 and the proper FSharp.Core)?

Comment: It is working now with hotfix. Thank you. :)

Comment: Great to hear, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I guess you must using that syntax:

```
 var H = MathNet.Symbolics.Infix.Parse "1/(a*b)";
```

Interesting note that the above function will return 1/(a*b) and not the solution of that calculation.  If you want H have the result, you must use:

```
 var H = MathNet.Symbolics.Infix.Parse "1/(a*b)";
 MathNet.Symbolics.Infix.Print(H);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I edited the question and I just followed what said here. [link](http://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/). but getting the error

Comment: Is MathNet correctly referenced in form (at top, USING MATHNET)? Are A and B correctly initialized? Are MathNet and NET Framework the same version?

Comment: Yes it is. "Infix.Print()" method works and other methods but "Infix.ParseOrUndefined" and "Infix.ParseOrThrow" threw and exception.

Comment: It can be related to the version of Infix. Try to update it or try to utilize only the Parse function (not ParseOrThrow or ParseOrUndefined).  I understand both functions can be answering 100% IF AND JUST IF you have problems with that variables - in this case, the first returns a ThrowException and the second returns Undefined...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way the library is used in the question.